# concatenate object querys results on foreign key in django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have two models from which I'd like to get one result on a foreign key.

```
# Master List:
class Block(models.Model):
    lesson = models.ForeignKey('Lesson')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

# Contains revisions, i.e. updates:
class BlockContent(models.Model):
    block = models.ForeignKey('Block')
    content = models.TextField()
    type = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    revision = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    latest = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

Ideally for template purposes, I'd like to be able to call `block.content` or `block.type` for instance, but this doesn't seem to be easily possible.

Getting the `BlockContent` by foreign key seems to be a pain- despite there only being a one-to-one result in this specific view, it requires .all() and a lots of iteration.

Stuff I've tried:

```
additional = BlockContent.objects.get(block=block.id)
block.blockcontent_set.add(additional)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have is a one to many relationship in which `Block` can have many `BlockContent` objects.

The way to get content from a block is by using reverse relation, I don't see a problem with that:

```
content = block.blockcontent_set.all()[0].content
```

to get the `content` of the first `blockcontent` in the queryset.

Of course `order_by` and all other queryset Django goodnes can be used here.

You could also define a related_name to:

```
class BlockContent(models.Model):
     block = models.ForeignKey('Block', related_name=blockcontent)
```

and use it like:

```
content = block.blockcontent.all()[0].content
```

Comment: @beezz that is simply not true at all. The queries are *exactly the same*.

Comment: @Daniel you are right. I checked Django's code and it is as you are saying. So sorry for the noise.